# "this" keyword for accessing parent element

Tags: typescript

I'm developing an application and i have to use this ugly hack to access the current class:

```js
export class ChatComponent implements OnInit {

  private mensajes: string[];

  // Some irrelevant code here

  private conexionWebsocket() {
    this.websocket = new SockJS(this.serverUrl);
    this.stompClient = Stomp.over(this.websocket);

    const that = this; // <--- Ugly Hack!!!

    this.stompClient.connect({ 'Authorization': this.token }, function (frame) {
        that.stompClient.subscribe('/chat', message => {
            that.mensajes.push(message.body); // <--- Ugly reference
        });
    });
  }

  // Some irrelevant code here
}
```

I tried using the same way as Java: `ChatComponent.this.mensajes`, without results.

There is another way to achive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an arrow function instead. They keep the same value of `this` that they had when they were defined.

```
this.stompClient.connect({ 'Authorization': this.token }, (frame) => {
  this.stompClient.subscribe('/chat', message => {
    this.mensajes.push(message.body);
  });
});
```

Comment: That worked! But i'm still curious, there isn't another way without an arrow function?

Comment: Another option is to use function.prototype.bind to create a copy of a function bound to a specific value of this. Before the invention of arrow functions, binding the function or using the `var that = this` approach were fairly common, but they're not needed as much nowadays.